# Is this behavior acceptable?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, unaccepted-answer

I found out my answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393653/receving-message-received-acknwoledgement-from-gcm-service) got unaccepted. I went and checked the answer that was accepted instead. While I didn't think it was more correct than my own answer, I thought it was the OP's right to change their mind.

Then for some reason I decided to check the [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2309359/addicted) of the person who answered the newly accepted answer. I found out that person has join SO today, and has 26 rep, all of them received from the OP of that question. I found out that this new user used his short time on SO (and his newly gained upvoting privileges) to cast 20 upvotes. While I couldn't see directly who got these upvotes, I went back to the profile of the OP of the question and can't say I was surprised to find that user just got [20 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343082/lasang?tab=reputation). What a coincidence :)

I was wondering what should I do with this information. I guess I could have simply flagged the question, but I thought you guys may enjoy it as much as I did, so I decided to share.

Comment: Looking into it now. You could also have flagged one of their posts to let a mod know what is going on. And yes - something looks odd there.

Comment: Nothing to see here... go on home, now... ;) (Socks put in the washer!)

Comment: When @AndrewBarber is at the rescue, Stack Exchange Town is safe! We should get you your own Bat Man sign, like the [Tim Stone one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140532/192622)

Comment: @HugoDozois Ooohhh... I am sufficiently jealous!